# Is it possible to use Jenkins without Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I've used Jenkins long ago and few days ago I've tried the current version. It seems that all build instructions now are made by Groovy scripts. I can't find in Jenkins documentation if it is possible to do it in the old way using UI? I believe Groovy has advantages but I don't know Groovy and old Jenkins functionality was enough to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to choose freestyle job and then you can use it the old way

Comment: here are some references:

Continuous integration with Jenkins - Tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html

Jenkins - Setup Build Jobs
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.html